# how can I run a SQL script remotely using redshift connector in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm running SQL statements in Python from EC2 like this

```py
import redshift_connector

# Connect to Redshift cluster using AWS credentials
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host = endpoint,
    database=db_name,
    user=username,
    password=password
)
    
conn.autocommit = True
cursor: redshift_connector.Cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('create table' etc.)
cursor.close()
```

That works, but how can I use the same DB connection to run an external script? I tried doing like this:

```
sqlfile = 'test.sql'

with open(sqlfile, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    commands = f.read().split(';')

for command in commands:
    cursor.execute(command)
    print(command)
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rs_manual.py", line 61, in <module>
    cursor.execute(command)
  File "/home/erapsvc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redshift_connector/cursor.py", line 211, in execute
    self._c.execute(self, operation, args)
  File "/home/erapsvc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redshift_connector/core.py", line 1275, in execute
    self.handle_messages(cursor)
  File "/home/erapsvc/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redshift_connector/core.py", line 1358, in handle_messages
    raise self.error
redshift_connector.error.ProgrammingError: query was empty
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run an external SQL script"? Wouldn't you just pass it to the `execute()` command?

Comment: Yes, trying but getting an error.

Comment: Please Edit your question to include details of the error you are receiving.

Comment: Does your SQL file end with a semicolon `;`? If that is the case, when you split your SQL file contents, the last element of the `commands` array would be an empty string. This is the main culprit which returns the `query was empty` error.